# Problem with MongoSwift. Compiler is unable to find "Mongo.h" file.

Tags: swift, swift4

I installed the MongoSwift 0.2.0 library through cocoapod. However when I try to open the project and build it I got 2 errors. "Mongoc.h" file not found and could not build Objective-C module "libmongoc".

I opened the project with the ". xcworkspace" file and installed Mongo-c-driver. So I'm not sure why I'm unable to get this library to work. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you installed and uploaded the cocoapod file ?